# Poor disk performance on FreeBSD

Tags: raid, freebsd, zfs

We have IO issues with our servers on FreeBSD and I am wondering if FreeBSD is the cause.

Server:

```
FreeBSD (our environment runs in a jail)
i7 8 cores (utilized around 10 - 20 %) 
64 GB RAM (utilized around 10 - 20 %) 
RAID Z2 of 6 WD 1 TB WD RE SATA III 7200 RPM 64 MB (WD1003FBYZ).
```

Test:

Copy 15 GB file on the same disk.

```
time cp file2.bin pepa2.bin

real    11m27.508s
user    0m0.168s
sys 0m13.306s
```

This means around 20 MB / s and the disc should have 128 MB / s sequential write speed, we reproduced the test on a second server with FreeBSD / ZFS and the result was similar. On similar server the same test run much faster (ca 100 MB / s).

Is it possible that FreeBSD / ZFS / RAID Z2 can cause such slowdown? Or is it just our configuration? Do you think that reinstalling the machine as debian would fix the issue?

Thanks

Comment: please show, your raid config